# Is there an angularjs util for automatically building dependency lists?

Tags: angularjs

For non-minified code, angular can automatically figure out dependency injections based on the parameter names you give to the callback functions of directives, controllers, services, etc.:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', function(myDependency1, myDependency2, myDependency3) {
        return whatever;
    });
```

However, if I want my code to be minify-able, I have to uglify it with a redundant list of dependencies like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', ['myDependency1', 'myDependency2', 'myDependency3', function(myDependency1, myDependency2, myDependency3) {
        return whatever;
    }]);
```

Not that that's terrible, but it's kind of annoying, and is an extra maintenance step that's always there.

Turning code sample 1 into code sample 2 is something that it wouldn't be too hard to teach a machine to do, so I'm guessing someone has already built a util that can automatically do that as a pre-minify step, so that code I actually work with can remain de-uglified and non-redundant.

Does anyone know of such a util out there?  I haven't had any luck finding one... I could probably build one, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if one already exists.

Comment: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it out. You should probably post that as an answer rather than a comment so it can be accepted/up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Dave's ng-annotate suggestion, I found that there is also a [gulp task](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-annotate) (or a [grunt task](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ng-annotate)) for auto-adding dependency lists during the build phase of the app.  I'm sure this is all old news for most of the angularjs people out there, but I thought I'd add it for other noob angular people that stumble across this question.

I wasn't using gulp or grunt at the time, but I'm a fan now (especially of gulp).  I used the base gulpfile.js [here](http://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp) but modified it to add an ngAnnotate() phase to the "scripts" task just before uglifying/minifying:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Compile Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())       // AWESOME!
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'sass', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Now my original source can be forever kept free of ugly, redundant annotation lists!